# What happened to ProteomeCommons.org?

Tags: mass-spectrometry, proteomics

[ProteomeCommons.org](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3560570/) seems to once have been a resource for raw proteomics data. Thought, the website now offers gardening tools. It seems to be hacked. Does anyone know whether the data is still available somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Lars Juhl Jensen on a Biostars forum](https://www.biostars.org/p/228388/),

> The Proteome Commons Tranche sadly shut down around 2013 due to lack of funding. It is a good example why important bioinformatics infrastructure needs dedicated funding and should not have to operate out of research grants for individual groups.

Comment: I have no quibble with your answer but feel the part of the quote regarding the need for dedicated funding is naive and simplistic. The fact is that it is difficult to get grant funding for web resources in the first place, but even more difficult to get extensions as granting bodies like to fund new projects. Thus KEGG got cut back and started charging for database access, and FlyBase likewise and is asking for subscriptions. This is a complex problem with no easy answers.

Answer (score 4):

They seem to have lost the domain name. I believe all the data from that project is now on [the UCSD site](http://proteomics.ucsd.edu/ProteoSAFe/datasets.jsp)